# Do I need to call requestLocationUpdates() if I just need to find the location once?

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

All I need is to find user's location when the app starts. Do I still need to create my own listener, implement all methods, and call `requestLocationUpdates()`? It just seems like a lot of useless code:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 999999999, 999999999, new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used it, but as of API level 9 there is a method called [requestSingleUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29) which might what you're looking for.

Another solution is to use `requestLocationUpdates` and unregister the listener immediately after you received the first update, for example:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    // do something with the received location
}
```

And in your use case you can leave the other methods of the listener blank, no need to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to but using `lastKnownLocation` does not guarantee you get an accurate location or even a location at all so you may end up using `requestLocationUpdates()` anyway to get an accurate location

Comment: So there's no way to just get an update **once**? It has to be a continuous periodic service?

Comment: yes there is using `getLastKnownLocation` but like I said there is no guarantee that the location is accurate or that there is even a location at all. all getLastKnownLocation does is get what the last cached location was

Comment: maybe you should look at using the `Fused location provider` in google play services http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: Yeah I just tried to use `getLastKnownLocation` and it returned `null`, so it's not really an update after all. I guess I have no choice but to call `requestLocationUpdates`

Comment: I really recommend using the fused location API because you can connect to it and just get a single location then you are done

Answer (score 0):

You can use  getLastKnownLocation(provider) to find the last location fix determined by a particular provider.

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Note that `getLastKnownLocation()` does not ask the Location provider to update the current position. So  if the device has not recently updated the current position this value may not exist or be out of date.
The location object returned includes all the position information available from the provider that supplied it like lat, long, bearing, altitude, speed and the time the location fix was taken.